# Project structure with v2 Go modules

Tags: go

I have a Go project with structure somewhat like this

```
github.com/my/coolproject
│
└───project
    │   file1.go
    │   file2.go
    │   go.mod (github.com/my/coolproject/project)
    │   ...
    │
    └───package1
        │   file1.go
        │   file2.go
        │
        ...
        │  
        packagex
        │   file1.go (import github.com/my/coolproject/project/package1)
        │   file2.go
```

I would like to create v2 of the project but not sure how to go about doing that.

I tried creating v2 directory at the root of the repo, copy content of the project folder into it and update the go.mod file to `github.com/my/coolproject/project/v2`

With this I also had to update the imports to v2 however the directory structure now didn't match precisely so I had to change imports from

`import github.com/my/coolproject/project/something` to `import github.com/my/coolproject/v2/something` removing the 'project' and adding 'v2'.

This causes bunch of cannot find module ... errors, when I remove the 'project' from the go.mod module path in v2 then it starts working.

However now there is a difference between the original project import path and the v2

`github.com/my/coolproject/project` for the original vs v2 `github.com/my/coolproject/v2`

Is there a way how to keep the original with just v2 at the end? The problem is that then it doesn't really match the folder structure. I though about moving the v2 folder with new version into the project folder, but that sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Don't rename any directories. Just add /v2 to the module path in go.mod and update your imports. It's okay that the directory structure doesn't include a directory named v2.

Comment: To my understanding, this is "merely" the best practice. It's not strictly mandatory. https://go.dev/blog/v2-go-modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I though about moving the v2 folder with new version into the project folder, but that sounds like a bad idea.

Yet it seems to follow the official Go wiki on "[Releasing Modules (v2 or Higher)](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#releasing-modules-v2-or-higher)"

> ### Major subdirectory:
>
> - Create a new v2 subdirectory (e.g., my/module/v2) and place a new `go.mod` file in that subdirectory.
>   The module path must end with `/v2`.
> - Copy or move the code into the v3 subdirectory.
> - Update import statements within the module to also use `/v2` (e.g., `import "github.com/my/module/v2/mypkg"`).
> - Tag the release with `v2.0.0`.

The other approach would be:

> ### Major branch:
>
> Update the `go.mod` file to include a `/v3` at the end of the module path in the module directive (e.g., `module github.com/my/module/v2`).
>
> - Update import statements within the module to also use `/v2` (e.g., `import "github.com/my/module/v2/mypkg"`).
> - Tag the release with `v2.0.0`.

No subfolder to create there.
And you can set your default branch to a `v2` branch instead of `main`, if you want people cloning your repository to get by default the latest version.